# What is Python's coerce() used for?

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-2.x, built-in

What are common uses for Python's built-in `coerce` function? I can see applying it if I do not know the `type` of a numeric value [as per the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#coerce), but do other common usages exist? I would guess that `coerce()` is also called when performing arithmetic computations, *e.g.* `x = 1.0 +2`. It's a built-in function, so presumably it has some potential common usage?

Comment: Never heard of `coerce()` (+1)

Comment: Deprecated, not used on Python 2.6 or 3

Comment: If you read the note at the top of the section of the documentation you linked to, you shouldn't use it, nor should you need to know it exists.

Comment: @Wooble coerce() was just far enough down that I missed the heading.  What was the usage?

Comment: Note: **Python programmers, trainers, students and book writers should feel free to bypass these functions without concerns about missing something important.**

Comment: I'm just trying to find a post I made on c.l.p on this, but no luck so far! LOL

Comment: My guess is coerce() was implemented as a work-around for some problem. Now that we found a better, more elegant way to solve that problem, coerce() is becoming obsolete.

Comment: Just because you "don't need to know" something doesn't mean you shouldn't *want* to know it.

Comment: Some of the thread that may (or may not) be of use http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.general/494305/match=list+typeerror (wow - can't believe I wrote that 6 years ago!)

Comment: related : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0208/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its a left over from [early python](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2/ref/numeric-types.html), it basically makes a tuple of numbers to be the same underlying number type e.g.

```
>>> type(10)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(10.0101010)
<type 'float'>
>>> nums = coerce(10, 10.001010)
>>> type(nums[0])
<type 'float'>
>>> type(nums[1])
<type 'float'>
```

It is also to allow objects to act like numbers with old classes
(a bad example of its usage here would be ...)

```
>>> class bad:
...     """ Dont do this, even if coerce was a good idea this simply
...         makes itself int ignoring type of other ! """
...     def __init__(self, s):
...             self.s = s
...     def __coerce__(self, other):
...             return (other, int(self.s))
... 
>>> coerce(10, bad("102"))
(102, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python core programing says:

> Function coerce () provides the programmer do not rely on the Python interpreter, but custom two numerical type conversion."

e.g.

```
>>> coerce(1, 2)
(1, 2)
>>>
>>> coerce(1.3, 134L)
(1.3, 134.0)
>>>
>>> coerce(1, 134L)
(1L, 134L)
>>>
>>> coerce(1j, 134L)
(1j, (134+0j))
>>>
>>> coerce(1.23-41j, 134L)
((1.23-41j), (134+0j))
```